# Job configurations are missing when copied from folders in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jobs, directory

This is reproducible 100%. 
We are working on different branches of the release, but each branch should run the same jobs, with some minor change.  So ideally I want to copy all the jobs from one working branch to a new branch.
I select a New item -> folder and select copy from another folder.
The new folder contains the all the jobs from source folder, but all the job configurations are missing. In another word, I have jobs created just with job names, I need to refill everything else.  This is essentially useless.

I googled and did not see any related errors. Anyone have any good advice on copy jenkins folders ?  I am jenkins 1.651.3, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: A simple, brute, but effective way to clone jenkins jobs is copying corresponding config.xml file between jobs subfolders on file system level (at /var/lib/jenkins ...). Better to shutdown Jenkins service doing this

Comment: hi thanks for your input. However I did exactly that and jenkins still doesn't show the proper configuration.  I can see the config.xml files are updated on the disk.  I also reload from disk/ and even shut down jenkins.  The jobs are still missing the right config.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same on jenkins 2.19.1 and worked with out the issue your are seeing.

The best way to create similar array of jobs for new branches is via groovy & using https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/

create a job where you execute a groovy script to iterate over a list of branches and creates jobs .

DSL plugin is available for jenkins 1.642 and above

Note that manipulating content in JENKINS_HOME is not advised and is typically restricted

Comment: Hi Thanks for your feedback. It turns out that it depends on how many jobs in the folder. If there are too many jobs jenkins cannot handle the copying and doesn't update the jobs properly.  My colleague copied a folder with 13 jobs and it worked with our Jenkins.  Mine folder contains over 30+ jobs and all jobs are empty.  So at this point I will not risk to upgrade Jenkins but will try DSL plugin you mentioned. Will report back if a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I should also mentioned it turns out just our computer issue. Lack of ram. After we added more ram, it' all working perfectly!